# Django OSError - [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/media/images' - are my MEDIA_URL and MEDIA_ROOT settings bad?

Tags: linux, django

There are a lot of questions revolving around this, but I'm still a little stumped. I'm getting the following error when uploading an image:

> OSError at /admin/past/article/add/
>
> [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/media/images'

I understand why this is happening having looked through all the other answers on this topic. What's catching me out is my MEDIA_URL and MEDIA_ROOT settings, which are as follows:

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, MEDIA_URL)
```

My manage.py for this app is at /home1/reconess/django-projects/Reconesse/manage.py, but because of the os.path.join for the MEDIA_ROOT setting, I'm not actually sure where the "/media/images" folder it's looking for should/would be. I am comfortable with Python, but don't have much experience with Django and have absolutely no clue when it comes to Linux.

So, my questions are:

- Is using os.path.join like this right?
- Where should I be putting my
  images? They are only to be uploaded by admins, if this makes a
  difference.
- Am I doing something stupid?

I am using fcgi, with my .fcgi file at /home1/reconess/public_html/testsite/testsite.fcgi

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Permission denied usually means that the UNIX user running the web server process does not have write access to the directory in the question. Please note that depending on your hosting setup your shell user is usually different from the user running the web server.

One way to solve this out is to

- Figure out what UNIX user is running FCGI process
- Give its group to write access to your media folder

Comment: That first point is one that I am not sure how to do. Any ideas? Would I also have to give the same permissions for every folder on that path?

Comment: chmod -r a+rwx media - however this is DANGEROUS on shared hosting - everybody can delete your files. Better to ask your hosting provider how to set up the permissions and users correctly.